# What's the best way to handle a "union" in a relational database?

Tags: database

I'm running into an annoying problem at work, where the domain model doesn't fit nicely into the relational model of our Postgres Database.

I have a bunch of primary tables A, B, C, etc. Then there's this other table X, that serves as basically a sub-collection for each of the primary tables. Thus, I want a one-to-many relation from each of the primary tables to X. Normally, a many-to-one relation is modeled by adding a foreign key from X to the primary table. However, in this case, I believe I would need a foreign key from X to *each* of the tables A, B, C, etc. This seems janky to me, especially since exactly one of these keys should be non-null at any time, e.g. a tuple in X should not belong to both A *and* B.

Is having `a_id`, `b_id`, `c_id` attributes in X the best solution, or is there an alternative approach?

Comment: What does it mean for table X to be a sub-collection of the other tables? I've never heard of a table being a collection or a sub-collection of any other. Does X have columns of its own besides the FKs? Also an ER digram would help.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova "subcollections" here does not refer to tables themselves, but to entities stored in them., i.e. entities in X can be members of collections of types A, B, C.

Comment: @X.L.Ant That would introduce a lot of duplication

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I mean that each entity a in A has a list of entities in X. For example, A could represent people and X could represent pets. Each person could have an indeterminate number of pets.

Comment: Have you considered adding join tables which map relations between the entities? A table for a2x, b2x, ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If X has a 1:M relationship with A, B and C (being X in the M side) but you want the FK pointing to A and the one pointing to B to be mutually exclusive, you have to add a check constraint to the table.

```sql
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT check_001 CHECK 
    ((a_id IS NULL and b_id IS NOT NULL) OR 
    (a_id IS NOT NULL and b_id IS NULL));
```

Comment: I usually use case expression returning 1 if it's non-null and 0 if it's null, and then sum up the case expressions returning an integer telling how many fields are non-null. Then the integer is compared with 1. But the answer is good enough, so you got my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The standard, normalized solution "by the book" is to add link tables X_A, X_B, X_C each one with two foreign keys. For example, in X_A:

- a_id referencing to A
- x_id referencing X, representing a 1:1 relationship!

However, if this is really worth to create these extra tables, or if you can live with a less normalized solution with a_id, b_id, c_id all in X, is heavily case dependent.

Comment: The one caveat with this is the possibility of having orphan records in X, which have no junction records in X_A, X_B, or X_C. This can be handled with triggers and/or stored procedures.

Comment: That solution is not equivalent to what OP wants.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova: ... because?

Comment: With that solution, how would you manage the fact that the relationships X->A and X->B have to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: The issue is this would create many-to-many relationships. As soon as you add association tables, there's nothing preventing one x object from being attached to multiple A objets. That's not a deal breaker, but it's less than ideal.

Comment: @gardenhead You can force 1:1 by means of either the PK or individual unique indexes on the columns you don't want repeated values on. But one person looking at the model would have the first impression of it being M:M which makes the real intention hard to read.

Comment: In addition to orphaned rows in X, what would prevent multiple join tables (X_A, X_B, X_C, etc.) from referencing the same x_id? You would have to apply some constraint to reference multiple tables.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to flip the key dependency.

Table `X` should have a single primary key, perhaps named `xid`, that is unique across the entire table. No foreign keys are needed.

Each row in `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` should also have a column named `xid`. If the relationship truly is 1:1, then `xid` could also serve as the primary key for `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` as well.

To join them you'd use

```
SELECT *
FROM   X
LEFT JOIN A on A.xid = X.xid
LEFT JOIN B on B.xid = X.xid
LEFT JOIN C on C.xid = X.xid
LEFT JOIN D on D.xid = X.xid
```

The above is just a basic [subtype/supertype database implementation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139092/is-my-implementation-of-type-subtype-design-pattern-for-mutually-exclusive-subc/139103#139103), nothing particularly unusual about it.

If you are greatly concerned about those extra joins causing unnecessary I/O, and only one of {A, B, C, D} will ever be valid for a given X, you could also add an additional attribute to help your query find the right table.  Just add an additional column to `X`, perhaps named `xtype`, containing a single character ("A","B","C", or "D"), and then write the joins like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   X
LEFT JOIN A on A.xid = X.xid AND x.xtype = 'A'
LEFT JOIN B on B.xid = X.xid AND x.xtype = 'B'
LEFT JOIN C on C.xid = X.xid AND x.xtype = 'C'
LEFT JOIN D on D.xid = X.xid AND x.xtype = 'D'
```

This will end up being slightly more efficient, because the query engine will not even bother trying to do a join to A, B, C, or D depending on `xtype`. The disadvantage here is that you need to keep `xtype` up to date, and there is no implicit constraint preventing you from setting an `xid` that points to `A` but an `xtype` that points to `B`. You'd have to implement that constraint yourself.

Comment: I want a one-to-many relationship from A to X, not one-to-one.

Comment: No problem. The solution will still work,  but you can't use `xid` as the primary key on `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D` is all.

Comment: ah, that is interesting, I've never considered that approach. All the foreign keys I've used have always been to primary key, unique columns.

Comment: Hm actually, it sounds like you're talking about a many-to-one relationship from A to X. I want the other way: one-to-many.